# How to make some content visible only to admin/mod users

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I would like to know what the best practice is to restrict access for the user to some parts of the content within my view. I am using CodeIgniter. When the user logs in I set the user data inside the session like this:

**controller**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_id);
//..
$this->load->view('view');
```

Now inside the view there are two `DIV`s. One should be visible to everybody and the other has to only be visible for admin or mods. Below is the code.

**view**

```
<div id="log_out">
//visible to everybody
</div>

//Is it possible to put this div as a part of if function? Something like this:
  //if <php $this->session->userdata('user_id') ?>

<div id="user_management">
//only visible to admin
</div>

//And how would I enclose the part that is restricted?
```

Or should this be done completely different? Should I store somewhere as what the user is currently logged in. If it is regular user, admin or mod? Thank you all in advance for reading and your replies.

Comment: You could use the PHP 'if' statement to check if the permission for admin is set, however you have implemented that. Then just echo admin-only content only if it is true. With the ?: operator you can probably do it very easily in one line.

Comment: I haven't all I have right now is the user ID, but I can use it to check in the DB what kind of rights does the user have. That is pretty much what I was asking for, where should I store the permissions?

Comment: Robert is completely correct in what he is saying. Make a separate view file for admins. Think of it this way - your view files are going to change. If you have admin functions in your view files that are viewable by the public - then every time you or anyone else makes any change to that view file - you risk exposing the admin functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that better solution is to divide that view to 2 separate views. Then check in controller if user is an admin (read that from session), and load both views if yes, and just one view if is not.

Comment: So another idea is to pass some extra parameter to view - e.g. $bIsAdmin (true if admin, false if not), then in every 'admin only' div:

`<div id="user_management" class="<?php isset($bIsAdmin) ? '' : 'hidden' ?>">
//only visible to admin
</div>`

Comment: Sorry the right code is: `<div id="user_management" class="<?php echo $bIsAdmin ? '' : 'hidden' ?>"> //only visible to admin </div>`
Remember that this solution doesn't remove this div's content from page source, it will just make it hidden in page.

Comment: welp, I tried putting this into my view.    `$xaxa = 'xa';` & `<?php if ($xaxa=='xa')
     {?>
    <div><p>xa</p></div>
    <?php}?>` But when I get on the page nothing's there, it's like the code ruins the entire view

Comment: neverming, I forgot to use the alternative syntax for view. This code works. `   <?php if ($xaxa == 'xa'): ?>
    <div><p>xa</p></div>
    <?php endif; ?> ` Now I just have to store the right values in the right places and it can be done. :)

Comment: You need to use echo statement if you want to do it your way. Curly bracket is not necessary in one line if condition.

Comment: This is going to work, but your code will become a nightmare soon. Please consider 'multi views' solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put a if condition something like this . 1 stands for admin in this case

```
   <?php if($this->session->userdata('usergroup') == '1') : ?>
   ---------do something---------
   <?php endif;?>
```